# SQL query to find resource containing more than one tag

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables.

```
Resource:
md5 (PK), link, title

Tags:
md5 (FK), category
```

it is a one to many relationship such that a resource can have a number of tags.
I want to be able to extract a resource that has both tags, for e.g. a resource that contains the tag 'web' and 'blog' in it. If I use 'OR', it will obviously return even document that contain only 'web' or only contain 'blog', but if I use AND, I get no results even though I know there are resources that contain both tags

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags.MD5, Resource.Title, Resource.Link, tags.Category
FROM Resource
INNER JOIN tags ON Resource.MD5 = tags.MD5
WHERE       
    (tags.Category = @tag)
OR
    (tags.Category = @tag2)
ORDER BY tags.MD5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do like that:

```
select t.MD5, r.Title, r.Link, t.Category
from Resource r inner join Tags t on r.MD5 = t.MD5
where exists (select category from Tags t1 where category = @tag and t1.MD5 = r.MD5)
and exists (select category from Tags t1 where category = @tag2 and t1.MD5 = r.MD5)
```

Comment: +1 This is a preferable solution if you want **all** tags for only those resources that have at least @tag AND @tag2.

Comment: Based on OP desired output, this is what's intended

Comment: The beauty of EXISTS is that is lets you easily handle other logic, like "resources with tag A OR B": `SELECT X FROM Y WHERE EXISTS (...) OR EXISTS (...)`.  It's extremely useful and, in my experience, very fast, typically faster than `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT IN ()` for anti-joins.

Comment: +1. Nice solution. In that way, even using a group by clause and group_concat(), you can have even all the other tags, not only those searched. Good job. :)

Answer (score 3):

The following will filter out resources that don't possess both tags:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Resource.MD5, Resource.Title, Resource.Link, t1.Category, t2.Category 
FROM Resource 
INNER JOIN tags t1 ON Resource.MD5 = t1.MD5 AND t1.category = @tag
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON Resource.MD5 = t2.MD5 AND t2.category = @tag2
```

Comment: I don't think the SQL is 100% valid but it's the right idea, so +1 anyway.

Comment: Oh, and if course if you want all the tags returned for those resources with both matching tags you can just join against tags for a third time.

Comment: @Neil Thanks, but: care to elaborate? What about the SQL isn't valid?

Comment: You use `r.MD5` when I think you mean `Resource.MD5` and you use `tags.Category` but both of your tags tables are aliased (although `tags.Category` could be correct if you joined against tags for a third time).

Comment: @Neil Ahh, good catches. I copied the SELECT list from the question and edited it hastily. Selecting `category` would be redundant in this case, so the fact the OP has it in there is further suggestion that @Adrian's solution is the appropriate one! :)

Comment: I still prefer your solution, but maybe that's because I'm used to an RDBMS that is better at optimising joins than exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
select r.*
from resource as r
left join tags as t
on r.md5 = t.md5
where t.category in ('web','blog')
group by r.md5
having count(distinct(t.category)) = 2
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. this works too but I will have to go with Adrian since exists gives a better performance.

Comment: No problem. I prefer his solution too. :)